# Hebrew sections with cjhebrew (and hyperef)

Tags: hyperref, hebrew

I sometimes write hebrew words in english or german texts. For this I use cjhebrew. It works fine unless I try to write a section or subsection in hebrew.
With

```
\subsection{\cjRL{kwl}}
```

I get

```
aTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/cjheb/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/cjheb/m/n' instead on input line 27.

! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.27   \subsection{\cjRL{kwl}}
```

(I tried \<...> before, same result).

The problem turned out to be an interference with hyperref.
Which I use to link sections and the toc in the pdf-document.
Is there an alternative either for hyperref or the section?

Comment: Can you produce a minimal working example?  On my system (which is, I think, a standard bundle), I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message is a typical for a broken command during the conversion
of section titles to bookmark strings.

Package `cjhebrew` uses a 7-bit font encoding for Hebrew that will not
work in bookmark strings. Also `\cjRL` is not expandable and
will not work either, even if the font problem could be solved.
But the macro can be disabled during bookmark generation:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\cjRL\@gobble % it can't be supported
}
```

The occurrences of `\cjRL` with their arguments are ignored in bookmarks.

To get Hebrew stuff in the bookmarks, `hyperref` needs option `unicode`, because
PDFDocEncoding does not contain the Hebrew letters. `\texorpdfstring` allows
to specify an alternative for the bookmarks.

The question remains, how to get Hebrew letters in bookmarks?

- If package `inputenc` is used with option `utf8` or `utf8x`, then
  the characters can be given directly. Package `hyperref` uses these
  characters directly (bypassing the conversion via LICRs).
- Since 2012/07/30 v6.82w: `\hebalef`, `\hebbet`, …
- `\unichar` is supported that expects a numerical Unicode value.
  Thus `U+05D0 HEBREW LETTER ALEF` can be addressed as
  `\unichar{"05D0}` or `\unichar{1488}`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\cjRL\@gobble % it can't be supported
}
\begin{document}
\cjRL{kwl}
\section{%
  \texorpdfstring{\cjRL{kwl}}%
  {\unichar{"05DB}\unichar{"05D5}\unichar{"05DC}}%
}

% with hyperref 2012/07/30 v6.82w or later
% \section{\texorpdfstring{\cjRL{kwl}}{\hebkaf\hebvav\heblamed}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This ought to be a comment, but I can't post it as such, owing to the picture.]

Could it be that you've got some interaction with other packages (if so, re-order), or a non-standard latex distribution? I ask because the following works fine on my system:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\begin{document}
\cjRL{kwl}
\section{\cjRL{kwl}}
\subsection{\cjRL{kwl}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\tableofcontents` to see the (standard) problem with moving arguments ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added `\tableofcontents`.  Still no problem.  Let me know if it would be useful to have the result posted here.  Not sure whether the questioner is still following this.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't had the time to solve this problem before. I searched for the package which might interfere and you were right. It turned out to be hyperref. I rephrase my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problems arise when using polyglossia with a Hebrew font and hyperref. It can be solved similarly to what Heiko Oberdiek does in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65174/23992):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Ezra SIL}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\ez}{\hebrewfont}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\texorpdfstring{\ez{ב}}{\unichar{"05D1}}}

\end{document}
```